# Does the Polybase shard range constitute data knowledge?

Tags: polybase

In the [Polybase database](https://docs.polybase.xyz), does the client encrypt and then determine in which shard a record belongs?

I was trying to understand how do you know the correct location of the data?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that’s how it will work initially. You can use zk-snarks to prove that this is the correct location for the data. This is detailed further in the [Polybase whitepaper](https://polybase.xyz/Polybase_A_Decentralised_Query_Index_and_Storage_Protocol-v2.0.pdf).

There is also ongoing research into homomorphic encryption (computing over encrypted data without access to the secret key), which would allow this to happen on the indexer.

Note: I'm a founder of Polybase.